# SQL insert new record after every unique code with next month as value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that I want to insert new records into. 
For every unique code, I want to add a new record for the next month with an amount of 0.

Example of input table:

```
Unique Code |  Date    | Amount 
    1       | 1/4/2015 | 100
    1       | 1/5/2015 | 20
    1       | 1/6/2015 | 30
    1       | 1/7/2015 | 80
    2       | 1/3/2018 | 55
    2       | 1/4/2018 | 60
    2       | 1/5/2018 | 36
    2       | 1/6/2018 | 90
```

The logic goes as such:

```
If the date < March - 2019 
Then ( Add a new row with Date + 1 month and an amount of 0) 
Else ( do nothing)
```

So the output table should be:

```
Unique Code |  Date    | Amount 
    1       | 1/4/2015 | 100
    1       | 1/5/2015 | 20
    1       | 1/6/2015 | 30
    1       | 1/7/2015 | 80
    1       | 1/8/2015 | 0
    2       | 1/3/2018 | 55
    2       | 1/4/2018 | 60
    2       | 1/5/2018 | 36
    2       | 1/6/2018 | 90
    2       | 1/7/2018 | 0
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow! SO tries to collect a number of curated, high-quality answers and questions. For new questions, you should be posting what you have tried so far, so you have better chances of getting a high-quality response. This is often called a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Now, on yo your problem, you should take a look at SQL statements for `DISTINCT`, and `ORDER BY`. You can construct a nested query that gets the `Date` for each DISTINCT `Unique Code` and then `INSERT` a new record for each one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want `union all`:

```
select uniquecode, date, amount
from t
union all
select uniquecode, dateadd(month, 1, max(date))  0
from t
group by uniquecode
having max(date) < '2019-03-01'
order by uniquecode, date;
```